# Firebase Database not writing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to write to my Firebase database however nothing is happening when doing so. Despite adding an `onCompleteListener`, nothing returns.

I am creating my custom object, and then trying to put that in my database.

Declaring the database:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase;
```

In onCreate:

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); // This returns the correct URL for my project
```

My code for creating the object is:

```
Party party = new Party(partyName, partyDescription, userUID, new ArrayList<PartyUser>(), isExplicitAllowedSwitch.isChecked());
```

My code to assign this to my database is:

```
mDatabase.child("party").child("1").setValue(party);
```

Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Also, I have noticed (this may not be related to the issue but..) That I can uninstall my app from my phone, reinstall it and it remembers the user that signed in with FirebaseAuth and even if I delete the user entirely!

The strange thing is that even if I set the value to something like "Hello", the same result occurs.

Comment: I've tried that. The same result occurs

Comment: Please add the code for your party class and any possible errors that you are getting. Currently the couple lines of code and your description is not enough to really help you. Also take a look at[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have you added "google-service.json" into the app folder?

Comment: Yes I have. I just had a little look around and it appears there is currently a bug where FirebaseDatabase isn't initializing for some automatically (Not sure why) I tried manually initializing it and that seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Please add the code for `Party` class.